# Querying the entity identifiers present in an XBRL instance with MarkLogic XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, xbrl

I am using MarkLogic's Xquery console to play around with it and query my XBRL documents

This is how my XBRL doc looks like

```
<xbrli:xbrl xml:lang="nl" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:bd-alg="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-algemeen" xmlns:bd-bedr="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedrijven" xmlns:bd-bedr-tuple="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedr-tuples" xmlns:bd-dim-mem="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-domain-members" xmlns:bd-dim-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/validation/bd-axes" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/entrypoints/bd-rpt-vpb-aangifte-2016.xsd"/>
     <xbrli:context id="ContextDurationDeclarant">
                <xbrli:entity>
                    <xbrli:identifier scheme="www.belastingdienst.nl/identificatie">800004449</xbrli:identifier>
                </xbrli:entity>
                <xbrli:period>
                    <xbrli:startDate>2016-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
                    <xbrli:endDate>2016-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
                </xbrli:period>
                <xbrli:scenario>
                    <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="bd-dim-dim:PartyDimension">bd-dim-mem:Declarant</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                </xbrli:scenario>
            </xbrli:context>
    </xbrli:xbrl>
```

As you can see it is XML.

The query i want to do is

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace lang="nl";
declare namespace link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase";
declare namespace bd-alg="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-algemeen";
declare namespace bd-bedr="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedrijven";
declare namespace bd-bedr-tuple="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedr-tuples";
declare namespace bd-dim-mem="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-domain-members";
declare namespace bd-dim-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/validation/bd-axes";
declare namespace xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi";
declare namespace xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";
declare namespace iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217";
declare namespace xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
declare namespace type="simple";
declare namespace href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/entrypoints/bd-rpt-vpb-aangifte-2016.xsd";

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Database dump</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <b>XML Content</b>
{
    for $xbrli:context in doc("test.xml")/xbrli:xbrl
    return
    <pre>
        Identifier: { $xbrli:context/xbrli:entity/xbrli:identifier }
    </pre>
}
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't see the problem but Xquery apparently does, because i only get empty sequences. Please help me!

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. Posting XML with prefixes without showing the namespace declarations is rather meaningless.

Comment: I now included the namepaces used within de XBRL snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Martin and Loren have a point, and I also have a few more comments specific to XBRL.

You need both to add `xbrli:context` in the XPath of the for clause, and to add `/string()` to the identifier to only get the string value (otherwise it will nest an element).

```
{
    for $xbrli:context in doc("test.xml")/xbrli:xbrl/xbrli:context
    return
    <pre>
        Identifier: { $xbrli:context/xbrli:entity/xbrli:identifier/string() }
    </pre>
}
```

The `xbrli:context` element must be outside of the return clause, because in the general case, **there are several contexts in the same XBRL instance**, but only one entity per context if the instance is conformant with XBRL.

Also, you may want to perform some duplicate elimination, because different contexts may contain the same entity. Actually, out of experience, **an XBRL instance very, very often contains only one entity across all its contexts**. This is the case with SEC filings and many other regulatory authorities (even though of course, XBRL places no restriction, so that other XBRL datasets may have several entities per instance).

Then `/string()` becomes superfluous.

```
{
  for $entity in distinct-values(
    doc("test.xml")/xbrli:xbrl/xbrli:context/xbrli:entity/xbrli:identifier
  )
  return <pre>Identifier: { $entity }</pre>
}
```

Actually, as `xbrli:identifier` will only appear at these places in a conformant XBRL instance, you can also use the descendant-or-self feature directly on this QName:

```
{
  for $entity in distinct-values(
    doc("test.xml")//xbrli:identifier
  )
  return <pre>Identifier: { $entity }</pre>
}
```

Finally, in many filings, an XBRL fact will even report a friendlier name for the entity (in SEC filings, it's `dei:EntityRegistrantName`), while the entity identifier will give you the CIK (also reported as `dei:EntityCentralIndexKey`).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
for $xbrl in doc("test.xml")//xbrli:xbrl
return
<pre>
    Identifier: { $xbrl/xbrli:context/xbrli:entity/xbrli:identifier/string() }
</pre>
```

You need the /string() at the end to get the content

I implemented it as the following:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace lang="nl";
declare namespace link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase";
declare namespace bd-alg="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-algemeen";
declare namespace bd-bedr="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedrijven";
declare namespace bd-bedr-tuple="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedr-tuples";
declare namespace bd-dim-mem="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-domain-members";
declare namespace bd-dim-dim="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/validation/bd-axes";
declare namespace xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi";
declare namespace xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";
declare namespace iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217";
declare namespace xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
declare namespace type="simple";
declare namespace href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/entrypoints/bd-rpt-vpb-aangifte-2016.xsd";

let $doc :=
  <xbrli:xbrl>
 <xbrli:context id="ContextDurationDeclarant">
            <xbrli:entity>
                <xbrli:identifier scheme="www.belastingdienst.nl/identificatie">800004449</xbrli:identifier>
            </xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:period>
                <xbrli:startDate>2016-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
                <xbrli:endDate>2016-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
            </xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:scenario>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="bd-dim-dim:PartyDimension">bd-dim-mem:Declarant</xbrldi:explicitMember>
            </xbrli:scenario>
        </xbrli:context>
</xbrli:xbrl>

                return
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Database dump</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <b>XML Content</b>
{
    for $xbrl in $doc
    return
    <pre>
        Identifier: { $xbrl/xbrli:context/xbrli:entity/xbrli:identifier/string() }
    </pre>
}
  </body>
</html>
```

The XML document does need the namespace declared

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi">
    <xbrli:context id="ContextDurationDeclarant">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="www.belastingdienst.nl/identificatie">800004449</xbrli:identifier>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2016-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2016-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
        <xbrli:scenario>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="bd-dim-dim:PartyDimension">bd-dim-mem:Declarant</xbrldi:explicitMember>
        </xbrli:scenario>
    </xbrli:context>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

Comment: This helps a bit, problem is i need to query documents directly and not define them inside the Query Console

Comment: Replace $doc with doc("test.xml")//xbrli:xbrl

Answer (score 2):

You have called your variable `$xbrli:context` yet you only select `doc("test.xml")/xbrli:xbrl` instead of `doc("test.xml")/xbrli:xbrl/xbrli:context` you seem to want.